# Draw a sectional oval

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I want to draw a sectional oval like the image attached.

[image]

The sections are dynamic and the area that the red color fills is also dynamic. 
Any idea on how this can be achieved. When the view will be drawn, it will have animation attached to it.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Extending a View class to draw the arcs but it's not smooth at all

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible subclassing view or drawable and using [Canvas.drawArc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint)), to draw the four oval section. For the round cap you can use

```
Paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND)
```